# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Array'

Tags: excel, windows, vb.net, com

I tried to read excel char with VB.net, I use VS2013 and Office2013

when I used LBOUND and UBOUND function, it cause this exception

the code is :

```
 Dim objApp As New Excel.Application
 Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

 objWorkbook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(path & FileName)
 objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(2)
 area = objWorkSheet.Range("a7", "a8")
 Debug.Print(LBound(area))
```

and the exception:

> 未处理System.InvalidCastException 
>   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=无法将类型为“System.__ComObject”的 COM 对象强制转换为类类型“System.Array”。表示 COM 组件的类型实例不能强制转换为不表示 COM 组件的类型；不过，只要基础 COM 组件支持对接口 IID 的 QueryInterface 调用，就能将这些实例强制转换为接口。

I search the google and not much useful information, so any help is appreciate.

Comment: Presumably `area` is an array variable and you can't assign the result of `Range` to that type of variable. Have you looked for working examples of getting cell ranges from Excel? I imagine that there are plenty around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Range` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel) returns a [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel). To get the value, use the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-value-property-excel) or [`Value2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel) property of the [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel). The value will be a 2D-array (matrix) when the [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) spans more than one cell. If the [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) only spans a single cell, the value will be a scalar.

```
Debug.Print(LBound(area.Value))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i also want to trans range object to matrix, now it kill two birds with one stone